# Finding a basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{4},\sqrt{3i+6})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I'm fairly certain that $\sqrt{3i+6}$ has degree 4, but other than the elements $1,i,\sqrt{3i+6}$, I'm not sure what else could be in that basis. I know the basis for $\sqrt[3]{4}$ is $\{1,\sqrt[3]{4} ,\sqrt[3]{16}\}$. Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: $\alpha=\sqrt{3i+6}$ is degree four over $\mathbb{Q}$. A natural basis to consider is $1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \alpha^3$; can you show that all of these are linearly independent? Once you have that, you can start asking what the degree of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)(\sqrt[3]{4})$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is...

Comment: Would cubing it end up implying that $\sqrt{i+2}$ is in the basis?